# Can't connect to mongodb in docker container from local machine

Tags: mongodb, docker, ubuntu

I have running docker container with mongodb on it
`someId mongo:3.6 "docker-entrypoint.s…"   11 days ago  Up 11 days  0.0.0.0:27017->27017/tcp  myMongo`
When I try to connect to that mongo from local machine via `mongo localhost:27017` I get en error

`error: couldn't connect to server localhost:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to localhost:27017 (127.0.0.1:27017) :: caused by :: Connection refused :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:328:13`

What I'm doing wrong?

**Update**
Here is an output from `docker-compose ps`

`myMongo       docker-entrypoint.sh --wir ...   Up      0.0.0.0:27017->27017/tcp`

Docker-compose file

```
version: '2'

services:
  mongo:
    image: "mongo:3.6"
    container_name: myMongo
    ports:
     - "27017:27017"
    mem_limit: 2G
```

**Update final**
Restarted my ubuntu, started the docker-compose once agin and all started to work as expected: `mongo localhost` now works. Suspect that there is a problem in ubuntu 18.04 logout process, because before that(and before system restart) I preformed logout/login several times

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43800164/connecting-to-local-mongodb-from-docker-container.

Comment: it won't connect since docker containers networks is separated from your local system network. So you need to run the docker with expose of port with your local system by following command: `docker run -d -e ROOT_URL=http://localhost -e MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017 --network="host"`

Comment: actually I start that docker process via `docker-compose` command. Updated the question

Comment: Then you also need to add host and docker ports mapping like ```ports:
   - 10005:80```

Comment: Then you also need to add host and docker ports mapping like ```ports:
   - 10005:80```

Comment: @krishnaPrasad port mapping is added. What do you mean under host mapping?

Comment: can you share your docker compose file? its clearly something wrong with your port mappings

Comment: @maks I mean host port and docker port mapping should be done before checking that it is connecting from host machine or not.

Comment: share you docker composer file content

Comment: @krishnaPrasad updated the question

Comment: @maks I have tried using mac and with provided docker-compose.yml and its working fine. Hope your issue resolved by restarting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps to start docker mongo containers and connect from local system:

1. Create docker `docker-compose.yml` file as :

   ```
   version: '2'
   services:
     mongo:
       image: "mongo:3.6"
       container_name: myMongo
       ports:
        - "27017:27017"
       mem_limit: 2G
   ```
2. Before making docker composer up, you should check that port 27017 is already occupied by some other processes or not as:

   ```
   netstat -an | grep 27017
   ```

   or

   ```
   lsof -i -P ;// look for the port 27017
   ```

   If port number 27017 is already occupied then you have to change the port number in the docker compose from 27027 to whatever you want to be.
3. start the docker container by below command [you have to be on the same directory wherever docker-compose.yml file is]

   ```
   docker-compose up
   ```

   check the below screenshot how the containers created and started 
   [image]
4. Now your docker container with mongo db 3.6 is up and running, open new terminal and connect with mongo shell as `mongo` if the default port is 27017 otherwise `mongo --port <whateverport number in docker compose>`

Hope this explanation help to you as well as someone else also :)

Comment: thanks, seems problem is with logout/login process on my ubuntu 18.04 as this happens when I perform logout and then login on running OS. Alternatively, if I reboot my OS - everything works fine