# Not able to acsess existing MongoDb from Spring Boot App Deploy in Docker Container

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, docker, dockerfile

I have been reading all sort of answers to connect my local MongoDB from Spring boot app which is deployed in Docker Container. 
But I am getting below error:

```
2020-04-24 06:39:29.425  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Adding discovered server 127.0.0.1:27017 to client view of cluster
2020-04-24 06:39:29.542  INFO 1 --- [127.0.0.1:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server 127.0.0.1:27017

com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:67) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.8.2.jar!/:na]
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:126) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.8.2.jar!/:na]
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:117) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.8.2.jar!/:na]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_252]
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:607) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStreamHelper.initialize(SocketStreamHelper.java:64) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.8.2.jar!/:na]
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:62) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.8.2.jar!/:na]
        ... 3 common frames omitted

2020-04-24 06:39:30.833  INFO 1 --- [           main] pertySourcedRequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped URL path [/v2/api-docs] onto method [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<springfox.documentation.spring.web.json.Json> springfox.documentation.swagger2.web.Swagger2Controller.getDocumentation(java.lang.String,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)]
```

If I run this spring boot app out of docker container, it works fine.
But from inside docker container its not able to access my mongoDB which is outside of docker container.
This how I am running docker container:

```
docker build -f .\Dockerfile -t dockerspringboot .
docker run -p 8085:8080 dockerspringboot
```

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:8
ADD build/libs/SpringBoot-1.0.jar SpringBoot-1.0.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "SpringBoot-1.0.jar"]
```

-I tried changing ipaddress to 0.0.0.0 and 127.0.0.1, but of no use.

-I tried changing mondod.conf with below commented/uncommented options:

```
# network interfaces
net:
  #port: 27017
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0
#  bindIpAll: true
#  bindIp: 127.0.0.1
```

-I tried changing firewall settings to allow all programs access to docker backend process as well.

Also tried changing local ipaddresses by using ipconfig command but still no luck.

Comment: what is your mongodb connection param?

Comment: These are the details of mongodb connection in spring boot app:     
 server.port=8080
spring.data.mongodb.host=127.0.0.1
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
sspring.data.mongodb.database=app1                                                                       in place of host, I tried changing all the different Ip addresses.

Comment: Post please full docker-compose file

Comment: I don't have docker compose file,I am having Dockerfile only, and  I am trying to run using "docker run -p 8085:8080 dockerspringboot" . Do I need to try it using docker-compose file ?

Comment: Try to connect to your MongoDB this way: `host.docker.internal:27017` [connecting to local mongodb from docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43800164/connecting-to-local-mongodb-from-docker-container)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify the authorizations to access the database if they exist, try this :

```
spring.data.mongodb.authentication-database=admin
spring.data.mongodb.database=app1
spring.data.mongodb.host=host.docker.internal
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.password=PASSWORD
spring.data.mongodb.username=USERNAME
```

Comment: Hey s.sofiane, I didn't added authorizations to the database, but I tried  changing spring.data.mongodb.host=127.0.0.1 to spring.data.mongodb.host=host.docker.internal  as you suggested and Its working now. Thanks you!!

Answer (score 0):

Add `--network="host"` to your docker run command. Then your docker container is able to access `localhost:27017`